# Any windows solution against using PFsense and squid maybe with AD or TMG

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, proxy

I want to make my server as proxy server and basically allocate all the resources like bandwidth etc.

My AD, DHCP, DNS server are one windows server so i would be happy if can do that by staying within that server so that evrything is on one computer.

Is it possible or i have to go for pfsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if you can use TMG on a server that already has AD, DHCP, and DNS?  Technically you can, although it would be a bad idea to do so on a production server.  For a test/lab environment, as long as you have enough hardware (RAM/CPU/etc) to handle the load.

As TMG is designed to live on the edge of your network, you may have to do some tweaking to the firewall rules to make sure that your internal traffic destined for AD/SMB is not blocked from your clients.

Comment: If its the good idea , then what is best proxy /bandiwdth solution for windows i mean any build in solution . In my uni we had an proxy server which we have to put in IE and then each user has its own defined internet quota nd print quota. How can i accomplish that

Comment: If I recall correctly, ISA has not offered bandwidth quotas (and I don't remember seeing that as a new feature of TMG).  I've heard goot things about DigiRain (http://digirain.com/en/), although I haven't used them myself (they plug-in to ISA and provide quota functionality).

Comment: basically ISA is TMG now i don't understand why did you said TMG is bad idea because TMG is big product then under what circumstances TMG is used or why TMG is made

Comment: It's not TMG that's a bad idea... it works great. It is the practice of sticking internal roles (such as AD) on the same server as internet facing roles (such as TMG, which is a firewall/proxy server). That applies no matter what firewall product we are talking about.

Comment: So basically in ideal enterprise system which uses TMG , it will be on the separate computer.AM i right?U mean to say that if i want to use tMG i have to make another VM and there i should install TMG